# Referencing a library built with an older .NET version

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bunch of libraries and apps built in .NET 6, but I need to reference a 3rd party library that's built on 4.8. I'm getting an error, because the lib is calling `System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext` at some point, which does not exist in newer .NET versions. After countless hours of trying to find a solution, I still can't make it work. At this point, I'm basically facing the prospect of having to downgrade a bunch of my libs/apps to 4.8. Asking this question is my last ditch effort to find a more elegant solution. Thank you! :)

Comment: No support for remoting in .NET 5+, work with the 3rd party to get ahead.

Comment: Microsoft explains that they stopped supporting Remoting, an architecture they identified as problematic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable